# WordPress Mega menu items showing twice

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress shopping website: http://windupbird.com.au/

I am using mega-menu. When i hover on menu items it show a drop-down menu where every item of the menu is showing twice. 
My mega menu is managed by Ebor Mega Menu (Screenshot Attached).
[Screenshot of Wordpress menus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZNRc.png)

Comment: What's in the home subitem if you collapse that?

Comment: Are you talking about inside WP-admin menus section ? If yes, I have attached a screenshot of WordPress menus in post.

Comment: I mean if you collapse the sub-item(homepages pages menu) what's in there

Comment: There is a reference of "Ebor Mega Menu" page ("Original: Homepages Mega Menu").  and on "Homepages Mega Menu" there are some short codes used.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/c11eb6 here is the screenshot.